# AngularJS communication between modules in different html files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are a couple of variables I want to share between two html files and two modules. Firstly, I used the service as follows but it did not work.
In vote.js:

```
var vote = angular.module('vote', []);
vote.service('voteParam', function () {
this.candidates = [];
this.show_result;
this.vote_begin;
this.elec_begin;
this.setValue = function (voteParam) {
    this.department = voteParam.department;
    this.group = voteParam.group;
    this.type = voteParam.type;
    this.round = voteParam.round;
    this.times = voteParam.times;
    this.advance_num = voteParam.advance_num;
 }
});
```

In vote-setting.js:

```
angular.module('admin')
.controller('vote_setting', function ($scope, $http, voteParam) {
 $scope.begin_vote = function () {
        init();
        startit();
        $scope.vote_begin = true;
        $scope.elec_begin = true;
        voteParam.vote_begin = true;
        voteParam.elec_begin = true;
        voteParam.show_result = false;
        voteParam.setValue($scope.voteParam);
        if (voteParam.candidates.length == 0) {
            $scope.get_candidate();
        }
    };
}
```

When the value is set as true in vote-setting.js, it is showed as undefined in vote.js. I think it's because when I import vote-setting.js in vote-setting.html, variables in the service are initialized again. Is there any other way I can make this work?

The service worked. But the value of variables in it get initialized when the js file is imported again. This is the key of this problem. Thanks

Comment: You are using two modules: vote and admin but you aren't providing vote to admin. Change to : angular.module('admin', ['vote'])

Comment: I did that. But it didn't work the way I want it

Answer (score 0):

Implement your shared data service as a factory.

Implement proper getter and setters.

Encapsulate your variables and only expose the getter, setters.

Example of shared data service (can also be used as a shared Model)

```
app.factory('voteParam', function() {
  var param1;
  var param2;
  var param3;

  return {
    setParam1: function(value){
      param1 = value;
    },
    getParam1: function(){
      return param1;
    },
    setParam2: function(value){
      param2 = value;
    },
    getParam2: function(){
      return param2;
    },
    setParam3: function(value){
      param3 = value;
    },
    getParam3: function(){
      return param3;
    }
  }
});
```

In an application this factory should be initialized once only.

If you are using 2 different angular applications (in your case 'vote' and 'admin') then use local storage or session storage to share data between them

Comment: It doesn't work. After I set the value in one module, I get a value of undefined in the other module. The factory got initialized when the js file is imported again.

Comment: The service should only be initialized once. If that's not the case you are using it wrong or have other problems. If you want to access data from a site that is not in your spa you could use local storage or indexdb.

Comment: Thanks. But the data is saved locally which is not the way I want it. I've decided to save variables in Redis which perfectly solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know the following:

Generally,an angular app should have only one base module. This is the module which you add to your html using `ng-app` directive. So your `html` content will know about only one angular app.

You can however create as many other modules as you would like or need. These can be custom modules as in your case, or these can be third party library (modules written by other developers for your ready use.). In any of the above case you need to add extra modules to your base module as dependencies as shown below:

angular.module('baseModule', ['extraModule1, extraModule2]);

Once you are done with this, any component like any `directive` , `service`, `factory` written in any of the extra modules shall be available to you for use, as if they were all written in your `baseModule`.

Having said this and coming to your question, the code provided by you doesn't seem sufficient to entirely diagnose your issue. However from whatever I get, I suggest you to add `vote` module to `admin` module or vice-versa. If you have any other module as a base module, you need to add both `vote` and `admin` as dependencies to that module.

Hope this helps you to start fixing the issue. Let me know if any thing seems unclear yet.

Comment: Sorry for not stating clearly my question. I did add vote module to admin module and the service worked, but not the way I wanted. For example, when I set the value of "show_result" to true in admin module, later I'll get a value of undefined in vote module. But I want it to be true. I think this is because vote.js which contains vote module are imported both in vote.html and admin.html. After I set the value, when I go to another page, the service is initialized again.

Comment: What do u mean by **vote.js is imported in vote.html and admin.html**. I hope you are not loading your `scripts` in each `html` page because this is not the way angular works or any other SPA should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My application consists of a management system and a  voting page where the system is a SPA and the voting page is not. But the voting page needs to get some values from the system. How could I make this happen? Thanks

Comment: You said **My application consists of a management system and a voting page where the system is a SPA and the voting page is not.** This means voting page is not at all the part of Angular SPA application. I believe we are talking here about 2 different applications altogether. Is that correct ? If yes, can you detail how these two application are connected at all

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to save variables in Redis which perfectly solves my problem.